# Adding button outside the binded Listbox in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have encountered a problem - i have created a project where i bind my code to xaml by using a bind to the listbox. However, it has created some problems in my future code - i want to add button to my form, but i encounter some errors.

> 'Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.'

This Error occurs when i try to bind something outside of my bindable Listbox.

> The property "VisualTree" can only be set once.

This Error occurs when i try to add button underneath the Listbox.

Can someone guide me on how can i fix this?

My code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsControl1">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

            <UniformGrid Columns="5">
            </UniformGrid>

        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The desirable result would be a button under the listbox.

Comment: "inside the Listbox, just underneath it" sounds contradictory. Put the Button *besides* the ListBox, into a common Panel, e.g. a StackPanel or Grid.

Comment: I have some vague general idea what you are trying, but please clarify where exactly you want the button to appear and why it's not outside the listbox instead.

Comment: @Clemens haha, thanks i fixed the mistake. " Put the Button besides the ListBox, into a common Panel, e.g. a StackPanel or Grid." This is when i receive the' Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your button **below** `ListBox` declaration.
Exceptions you are facing are thrown because visual tree is populated via binding and you cannot alter it manually anymore.
You will need to put all this stuff inside of some layout container (`Grid`, `StackPanel`, etc.), since you cannot set `Window`'s/`UserControl`'s `Content` property twice:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="ItemsControl1">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                <UniformGrid Columns="5">
                </UniformGrid>

            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The property 'Content' is set more than once. This is the error i get when i declare my button below the listbox.

Comment: Place listbox with button inside some container (e.g. `StackPanel`, `Grid`)

Comment: Thank you! I added grid around my Listbox and then added         <StackPanel>
            <Button >s</Button>
        </StackPanel>  underneath the list in stackpanel.